# dynamically added class not retained on leaflet marker

Tags: esri-leaflet

I am trying to add an active class to the marker that was clicked by the user. For this, I am storing the clicked marker's icon in a variable and doing the following

```
let activeMarker = e.target._icon;
activeMarker.classList.add('leaflet-marker-active');
```

Since we are showing more than 500 points, I use the map.flyTo function to flyTo the selected marker's position and then use map.invalidateMapSize() as well.

With all this, once the map is completely loaded, the active class added disappears from the marker. The markers keep on refreshing and redrawn, as a result of which the active marker class is not retained.

How can we add class to leaflet marker, such that it is not removed even when we move the map or drag the map?

Answer (score 1):

you'd be better served to use the methods built into `L.esri.featureLayer` to programmatically alter feature styling than trying to manipulate the underlying DOM yourself.

API reference: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/feature-layer.html

```
fl.on('click', function (e) {
  fl.setFeatureStyle(e.layer.feature.id, function (feature) {
    return { color: 'green', weight: 2 };
  });
})
```

http://jsbin.com/wewulot/edit?html,output